# Custom table filtering for MSTeams using fluentui/northstar

Tags: microsoft-teams, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am developing a custom tab for the MS Teams using the fluentui/react-northstar v0.51.4

I have a requirement to have a table with the capability of Sorting, Filtering, and Paging the table.

I am not able to find any of the details for the same.

If you can provide a demo that will be more helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tables aren't inherently MS Teams feature(which includes Messaging Extension, Tabs, Bots & Connectors), Since adding tables to custom tabs is similar to adding the same on webpages. So there are no samples listed with tables in official GitHub repo. I would suggest you to refer to Data Tables. You can refer more info [here](https://datatables.net/)